# xsl:choose / xsl:otherwise not working for me

Tags: xml, xslt

The below works when the tag `HOST_NAME` is not blank, but when it is, the 'otherwise' isn't returning the `ASSET_TYPE` tag. I feel like this must be something simple, but I can't see it no matter what I try:

```
<xsl:variable name="vhostname">
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="ASSET/HOST_NAME !=''">
   <xsl:value-of select="ASSET/HOST_NAME" />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
   <xsl:value-of select="/CHECKLIST/ASSET/ASSET_TYPE" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

The XML is:

```
<CHECKLIST>
 <ASSET>
  <ASSET_TYPE>Computing</ASSET_TYPE>
  <HOST_NAME></HOST_NAME>
  <HOST_IP></HOST_IP>
  <HOST_MAC></HOST_MAC>
  <HOST_GUID></HOST_GUID>
  <HOST_FQDN></HOST_FQDN>
  <TECH_AREA></TECH_AREA>
  <TARGET_KEY></TARGET_KEY>
 </ASSET>
</CHECKLIST>
```

Comment: You need to give us more context (ideally a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). It's working here: http://xsltransform.net/bnnZWG

Comment: I agree with @DanielHaley, but note that all of your XPaths are relative except for the one in `xsl:otherwise`, which is absolute.  Perhaps in a larger context you intended it too to be relative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify your code like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="vhostname">
 <xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="string(ASSET/HOST_NAME/text())">
   <xsl:value-of select="ASSET/HOST_NAME/text()" />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
   <xsl:value-of select="ASSET/ASSET_TYPE/text()" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```